# Publishing android app in market

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish an app for free on android market. I want to keep most of the features free but if the user upgrades (by paying), I want to replace certain free features with modified/enhanced ones.

I wanted to know how the procedure is carried out; I mean how to handle the free vs paid features. I would be glad if someone showed some insights. Is there any single document/procedure which explains this?

I was going through the following links:

a)[Publishing](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html)

b)[Publishing overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html)

c)[Preparing for release](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html)

d)[Quality guidelines](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/core.html)

However, it seemed like they don't explain these things thoroughly enough. Any help would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to look at in-app billing. [Here's the guide/documentation from the Android site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html).

You might also want to view [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html), which has a working demo.

Comment: and how do make certain features available based on whether the user has paid for it or not ?..Initially, do i need to keep them disabled/hidden and when user pays, make them available ?

Comment: It is all explained in them links, http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html. Look for "Querying for Purchased Items". More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html.

Comment: i don't want any purchasing of items. Actually, i want to enable/disable certain features if user pays. Can it be handled under licensing ? like, when appln does a check, can i customize it to check whether the user has paid or not and then enable/disable them ?